# how to add acumatica msdl file to cloud?

Tags: acumatica

we have a cloud based acumatica. we want to add or remove some field from a mobile screen. we were told we can use msdl code to do this. it seems so easy to add msd file into the mobile folder, but after search through all framework guide, I still don't have a clue to do this for could base acumatica since I don't have access to any website folder. anyone knows if it is achievable for cloud base installation?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using cloud, but can you simply upload to the cloud in a customization package?  On 2018 R1, I added the xml files on a customization project.  In 2018 R2, you use the new section in Customization Projects for Mobile Application to add/update screens in the mobile application using MSDL.  In either case, publishing the customization project should deploy your updates for mobile.  Not being a cloud customer, I'm curious if this is the same solution for you.

Answer (score -1):

If you are the customer of Acumatica SaaS (in this case your Acumatica site URL looks like %somename%.acumatica.com), you need to submit a support case on https://portal.acumatica.com and SaaS team will process the request.

In other cases, you probably need to contact someone who deployed the installation of acumatica into cloud for you. These guys usually have a Remote Desktop access to the Application Server with the permissions to adjust web application folders.